# Панель Инструментов Андроид Студио сместилась в бок. Как вернуть назад?

Tags: android, android-studio, настройки

В результате неудачных манипуляций Панель Инструментов сместилась.

Как вернуть назад панель? И вообще, **Как и где грамотно настраивать панели**?

P.S. Искал! Но не нашел! И не догадался! )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Вернуть обратно:*

Выберите `View->` Щелкните `Toolbars`

*Настраивать:*

На панели инструментов (`Toolbars`) правой кнопкой мыши выберите `Customize Menus and Toolbars...`